# Hiding File Name From URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, url-rewriting

Can you please let me know how I can hide a Page name from URL in PHP or HTML? For example if I have something like:

```
www.mydomain.com/about.html
www.mydomain.com/project.html
www.mydomain.com/contact.php
```

only be shown as:

```
www.mydomain.com
```

I already saw this trick using

Add the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
#######
#Allow PHP/HTML pages to load without the filename extension
######
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

but this only removes the extensions. Thanks

Comment: Please don't do this. You're providing a horrible user experience by making it impossible to create deep links into your content.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe you can accomplish what you want another way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iFrame.

```
<iframe src="about.html" name="nameOfFrame" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"> This is the text that will be displayed for browsers not supporting iframes. </iframe>
```

This would wrap the whole page in an iframe, so you would do this on your index.html page, and take the contents of your index.html page and put it in "home.html" or something.

For a hyperlink outside of the iframe you'd just do

```
<a href="page.html" target="nameOfFrame">Hey guys!</a>
```

Probably not the best method here, but it'd "work".. one downside is if someone goes directly to "mydomain.com/about.html" it'll take them to the about page with /about.html in the address bar. This method also makes it hard for viewers to share your page.

Another method would be to use AngularJs and UIRouter. I've only used it a little, so I can't just throw some code out, like I did with inline frames, but you can read more about it here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Not possible**. You cannot change what the browser displays in the address bar to that level. it is a MAJOR security issue. You can do simple things like hide a file extension or change a query parameter to a "path" component, but you cannot convince a user's browser to fundamentally lie to them.

Your ONLY hope in this case is to use `<frameset>` so that the address bar stays at your top level page, and the individual pages are buried inside `<frame>`s. And even that is pointless. It is *beyond trivial* to get the address of any page "hidden" inside frames like that.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your case is:

```
www.yourdomain.com/about/index.html
www.yourdomain.com/project/index.html
www.yourdomain.com/contact/index.php
```

as we all know that files with index wont appear in url then you will be Ok but consider that when you link your pages `<a href="../about">` that's the right one. [do not do that -> `<a href="../about/index.html">`]

in order to avoid the appearance of the file extensions,  I do have a quick and easy way that I personally use it, which you should make a folder for each file put the file in its folder, and name the folder as the file name and change the file name to index.html then try to avoid mentioning the file name in "<a href='' " tags instead of using index.html just write the folder name and then you will be Okey!
the use case and example for about.html
1- make a folder name it about
2- put the about.html in the about folder
3- change the about.html to index.html
4- delete all the (.html)s in your href links

inorder to make it clear for you, let's say you have index.html and about.html, you should create a new folder and name it (about) then you can cut and paste your about.html in (about)FOLDER that's it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).